# How do you use the Swiper callback methods in React?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have a component class and need to be able to use `.slideToLoop()` and `.update()`, and haven't been able to figure out how to use those methods with the Swiper React library.

I need to do this when something else is clicked on, so that the Swiper can update (as it's hidden initially), and then slideTo the relevant slide.

At the moment, I have the click trigger in jQuery in `componentDidMount()` as I'm porting things over into React. But happy to change this as well if it's better to. The click happens on a grandchild component.
And I have the swiper instance being set into the state, but that happens after `componentDidMount`, so I can't access it from there.

Code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      swiperIns: ''
    }
  }
  
  setSwiper = (swiper) => {
    this.setState({swiperIns: swiper}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.swiperIns);
    });
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const { appStore } = this.props;
    if (!appStore.hasLoadedHomePage)
      appStore.loadHomePage().catch((ex) => null);
      
     const mySwiper = this.state.swiperIns;
     console.log(mySwiper); // returns ''
      
      $('.modal-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var modalToOpen = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
         console.log(modalToOpen);
             if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('data-slideindex')) {
                 const slideTo = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slideindex'));
                 // this.state.slideToLoop(slideTo);
             }

             $('#' + modalToOpen).show();
             $('body').addClass('modal-open');
             
             if ($('#' + modalToOpen).hasClass('modal--swiper')) {
                 // this.state.swiperIns.update();
             }
     });
  }
```

and the return part of the Swiper:

```
<Swiper onSwiper={ this.setSwiper } spaceBetween={0} slidesPerView={1} loop>
...
</Swiper>
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out.
First, you add a ref to the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.swiperRef = React.createRef();
}
```

And in `componentDidMount`, like so:

```
const mySwiper = this.swiperRef;
```

And then on the Swiper element, you set the ref to the Swiper instance like so:

```
<Swiper ref={ this.swiperRef }...</Swiper>
```

And then in button clicks/functions, you can use `this.swiperRef.current?.swiper.slideNext();` or any other Swiper callback methods to update/slideTo/etc.